# Why am i getting the error 'Type ViewController does not conform to protocol UIPageViewControllerDataSource'?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, datasource, uipageviewcontroller

I am looking to set up a VC that handles my UIPageViewControllerDataSource but for whatever reason I am getting this error. Is there another protocol I need to include. My code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the protocol definition for your custom class is not enough. You have to provide at least the two required functions of the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` protocol:

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? 

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
```

Take a close look at the methods you can implement within your class in the [UIPageViewControllerDataSource Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerDataSourceProtocolRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPageViewControllerDataSource/pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the following methods:

- pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
- pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?